# How to solve a ratio question

Tags: fractions, rational-numbers, gre-exam

Studying for the GRE. In the GRE guide, it says that

> If the ratio is $2x:5y$, and this equals the ratio $3:4$, what is the ratio of $x:y$?

I tried cross multiplying but I don't get the answer. It says the answer is $15:8$. I get $8:15$. Which step am I missing?

Comment: You set ${2x\over 5y}={3\over4}$. Then solve for $x\over y$.  From what you wrote, I surmise you solved for $y\over x$, which is the ratio $y:x$.

Comment: Once I get to 8x = 15y, how do I solve further?

Comment: Divide both sides by $8y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are given: $$\dfrac {2x}{5y} = \frac 34$$

$$2x\cdot (4) = 5y \cdot (3)\tag{1}$$ $$ \iff 8x = 15 y\tag{2: cross-multiplied}$$ $$\iff \frac {8x}{y} = 15\tag{divide by y}$$ $$ \iff \frac xy = \frac{15}{8}\tag{divide by 8}$$

It seems as though you went from $(2)$ to $\dfrac {8x}{15y} = 1$, concluding the ratio is $8:15$. But we want $x: y$ which is the value of $\dfrac xy$, so $$\frac {8x}{15y} = 1 \iff \dfrac{8x}{15y}\cdot  \dfrac{15}{8} = 1\cdot \dfrac{15}{8} \iff  \dfrac xy = \dfrac{15}{8}$$

Rather than cross-multiplying, it makes more sense in this problem to start from the given $$\frac {2x}{5y} = \frac 34 \iff \frac {2x}{5y}\cdot \frac 52 = \frac 34 \cdot \frac 52 \iff \frac xy = \frac{15}{8}$$

Comment: Ohh ok! I get it now! thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Nice feedback ... +1

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the following equation:

Given that

$\dfrac{2x}{5y} = \dfrac{3}{4}$

Multiply both sides by $\dfrac52$.

$\dfrac{x}{y} = \dfrac{15}{8}$